# Show related field from product template on account move

Tags: odoo-15

I'd like to show intrastat_id field that is on product form in account move (when creating invoices)

I'm inheriting it like this

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move.line'
 
product_template_id = fields.Many2one('product.template')
intra_stat = fields.Many2one(related="product_template_id.intrastat_id", string='Intrastat #')
```

It shows nothing - blank field in lines. What am I doing wrong? I double checked if Intrastat (commodity code) is set on product.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your *product_template_id* field value is False. *account.move.line* has *product_id* field which auto set during stock journal entry creation.

In your case, you should remove the product.template table approach and focus on product.product table.

Also do not forget to register intrastat_id into product.product table if you don't already declared.

For example: Declare following field in the *account.move.line* object:

```
intra_stat = fields.Many2one(related="product_id.intrastat_id", string='Intrastat #')
```

Comment: Got another solution: 
intra_stat = fields.Many2one(related="product_id.intrastat_id", string='Intrastat #')

But I'm curious - what do you mean by registering intrastat_id into product.product table? Something like this maybe:

class Prd(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    intrastat_id = fields.Many2one(string="Intrastat")
    
class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move.line'
    product = fields.Many2one('product.product')
    intra_stat = fields.Many2one(related="product_product", string='Intrastat #')

Comment: I edited my answer for more clear example. And no need to add *product* field in *account.move.line* because it has already field called *product_id* If you read my answer carefully, it has same solution that I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Bhavesh, now I see it.